# Xamarin iOS toolbar background image

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to put image as background in toolbar in Xamarin Forms in iOS project with master detail page and navigation bar (to have software back button in iOS). On android it works well but in iOS not good enough. I use this code in AppDelegate.cs:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage("toolbar_iOS.jpg"), UIBarPosition.Any, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

I put here image with pattern 400x125 pixels (less width - it displays 1 image and part of second image to the right, more pixels - image is zoomed).  I want to have image displayed as aspect fill, because at page just under toolbar I have the same image with pattern and I want them exactly in the same size to match pattern.

Second way was to put an image in stack layout in Xamarin.Forms in NavigationPage.TitleView. I can modify aspect, but image is displayed only in about 70% of area of toolbar (it bypass hamburger icon and status bar), so it is not good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Layout.xxx.Views.MainMenuPage"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Layout.xxx.Views">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MainMenuPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainMenuPageDetail x:Name="DetailPage">
                    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
                        <Grid>
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Margin="-50,-30,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout.Margin>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="-35,0,0,0" Android="-60,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackLayout.Margin>
                                <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Margin="0" Source="logo_svg.svg" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
                </pages:MainMenuPageDetail>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Negative margins does not help. Is there another way to have control over toolbar image in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code snippet , may help

<ContentPage>
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
        <Image Source="iconXamagon.png">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image.TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="HandleTapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Label Text="3.2.0" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
....
```

Comment: This is the second way that I have just described in topic. It covers only about 70% of toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `HasBackButton="False"` for the page it should cover the whole screen, just you will have to implement the back button or the hamburger button yourself.